# Is there any technical, mathematical or logical, terminology for a set of propositions, all of which cannot be True at the same time.

Tags: logic, terminology, formal-systems

As the question states, what is the technical term (if any) for a set of propositions which cannot all be true at the same time.

That is to say,

If there is a set,
 $A${x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>, ... , x<sub>n</sub>}
for which the statement,
 $x$ is true $\forall x\in A$.
is necessarily a contradiction,

What is the technical term (if any) for such a set.

Comment: It is called inconsistent

Comment: Thanks!
And is there any term for an inconsistent set all of whose subsets are consistent?

Comment: @ZarakshR "Minimal(ly) inconsistent." (I presume you mean "*proper* subsets.")

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.
And, yeah I meant proper subsets, I should have clarified.